# RoR ActiveRecord Join Help or Alternative Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Working on a RoR app. Think Tinder for art with a little basic AI. As you like or dislike art the app will show you art that you will hopefully like more based on other users’ preferences. I am working on the code to pick the next image to show.

I use the following models:

Basic user info:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :artworks
  has_many :artists
  has_many :art_views
end
```

Info about each piece (price, height, width, etc)

```
class Artwork < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :art_views
end
```

To represent which art has been show to a user (boolean liked indicates if the user liked the artwork)

```
class ArtView < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :artwork
end
```

The logic is simple: after finding the last Artwork liked by current_user (in ArtView), find other Users who also liked the same Artwork (also in ArtView) then find new Artwork liked by those other Users that has not been seen by the current_user (no record in ArtView)

I tried using the following join to find Artwork that meets this requirement:

```
@artwork = Artwork.joins(:art_views)
  .where(:art_views => { :liked => true})
  .where(:art_views => { :artwork_id => @artwork_id})
  .where.not(:art_views => { user_id: @id })
```

But it doesn't work.

Instead, I am now trying to do it more "step by step" and am trying to just find ArtViews where with similar requirements:

Find ArtViews for a specific user_id where the user liked the ArtView, but do not include art seen by a different specified user_id

I am trying the following code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
@artview = ArtView.where(user_id: @similarUser, liked: true).where.not(user_id: @current_user.id)
```

Any help (either fixing the join or fixing the work around) would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I as able to solve this using a scope that I hacked together based on more digging here on SO (but I lost the tab that the other answer was in, so unfortunately can't reference it for you).

I added the following scopes to the ArtView model:

```
scope :all_except_user, ->(user) { where.not(user_id: user) }
scope :all_except_art, ->(artwork) { where.not(artwork_id: artwork) }
```

Then I used the following code in the controller:

```
@lastViewed = ArtView.where(user_id: @id, liked: true).last
@artwork_id = @lastViewed.artwork_id
@allViewed = ArtView.where(user_id: @id)
@similarUsers = ArtView.where(artwork_id: @artwork_id, liked: true).all_except_user(@id) 
@similarUser = @similarUsers.first
@similarUserId = @similarUser.user_id
@alreadyViewedArt = Artwork.joins(:art_views).where(:art_views => { :user_id => @id})
@similarArtworks = ArtView.where(user_id: @similarUserId, liked: true).all_except_art(@alreadyViewedArt.ids)
@nextArtwork = @similarArtworks.first
@art = Artwork.find(@nextArtwork.id)
```

I'm certain there are more efficient ways to write this code, but at least it works and I can work to make it more efficient with proper joins at some point in the future. Hopefully this answer helps some others.